# Can you help me what's wrong with all the phrase behind while-if-break?

Tags: java

```
public class Main{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n=0;
        while(n<10) {
            if(n<5) {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(n); n++;
        }
    }
}
```

here, I think `while` can continue to run after `if` but compile error all phrase behind else-break!
like `System.out.println(n); n++;`

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with how to ask questions on StackOverflow. That said, no, the block of the while loop will either run into the `continue` statement or the `break` statement above the `System.out.println...`, because either the `if` or `else` block will happen. There is no third option, where neither block is executed.

Comment: Imagine this, you access your while loop, then encounter the`if` statement. So, if `n<5` you will `continue`, which means you will continue at the top of your loop. You will never increase `n`. If you were to increase `n` though, you would also never execute the `System.out.println()` statement, as once `n>=5`, you will `break` out of your loop in your `else`.

Comment: It is just unreachable code. You can check manually with some sample inputs.

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println(n); n++;` is unreachable because both the `if` and the `else` blocks either exit the loop or jump to the next iteration.

`continue` will cause the loop to immediately go back to the start, skipping the rest of the code in the loop.

`break` will immediately exit the loop and continuing execution after it. Therefore, it also skips the rest of the loop body.

Comment: Thank you!! it's only 2 way if or else!

Answer (score 1):

If you get an error and ask a question on Stackoverflow, please always post the error output or your console (could also be a screenshot pasted as image).

Reproducing [your example](https://ideone.com/scd77i) showed following **compiler error**:

> Main.java:18: error: unreachable statement

> ```
>        System.out.println(n); n++;
> ```

Now you and we can start analysing, or even spot the error directly:

### Compiler error explained

Here (line 18) **unreachable statement** means that `System.out.println(n);` will never be reached. This is because the previous if-statement already terminates the current iteration of your loop. It either `break`s or `continue`s:

```java
if (n < 5) {
  continue;
} else {
  break;
}
```

#### Analysis of the code

From your code I assume, that you want to loop exactly 5 times (iterations), from `n=0` to `n=4`. Like in this [quick-fixed demo](https://ideone.com/qJVpLK).

But in your case the counter variable `n` will never be increased, because `n++` after the `println` is also never reached. So the program would be stuck in an **infinite loop**. Good that the compiler warned you.

### Solution

Here's how you could fix at first:

1. Move the `println(n)` and `n++` to print the counter for each iteration and afterwards increase directly, before the `if` (5 lines on console).
2. Invert the `if` statement to test for `n >= 5` and `break` then
3. Remove the `else` and it's consequence `continue`

The `else .. continue` is obsolete, because a loop will always continue with the next iteration.

Ask yourself: Why should it **`break` on the 6th iteration** (when n=5) ?

```java
int n=0;
while (n < 10) {
    System.out.println(n); // starts with 0 and will reach until 9
    n++;
    if (n >= 5) { // n starts with 1 and breaks starting with 5
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("What should happen here? n=" + n); // because it will reach here from 1 to 4
}
```

Test this [solution on IDEone](https://ideone.com/eXiN2S).

Not sure if this does what you wanted.
Please **update your question** and tell us your requirement (what you expected/wanted to achieve)!